# black screen on the second monitor connected trought RDP on Fedora

Tags: fedora, macos, rdp

My linux machine

```bash
bruno@fedora:/$ cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="39 (Workstation Edition)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=39
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f39"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora Linux 39 (Workstation Edition)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;38;2;60;110;180"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:39"
DEFAULT_HOSTNAME="fedora"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f39/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://ask.fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=39
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=39
SUPPORT_END=2024-11-12
VARIANT="Workstation Edition"
VARIANT_ID=workstation
bruno@fedora:/$
```

I'm using a Mac Studio M1,
I installed Microsoft Remote Desktop (https://apps.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id1295203466?mt=12)

I did a successful connection and works flawless with a single monitor.

Issue 1:

- Now I have a second monitor, when connected the second monitor is all black
  (in the configuration is to use all monitors)

Issue 2:

- In the configuration is unchecked "All monitors", when I click in "Enter full screen" my expectation is use a full screen of the  second monitor but it goes to issue 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution on this link

https://kb.parallels.com/en/111936

1. Go to Apple logo > System Preferences > Mission Control.
2. Enable Displays have separate Spaces option.